# UISegmentedControl Bar style equivalaent in Android

Tags: android

Is there any control in Android which is similar to UISegmentedControl Bar style in iPhone?

The Bar style is the button from following view (the background is a separate control, the two buttons stick together)

[alt text http://c0848462.cdn.cloudfiles.rackspacecloud.com/8b7e0e7d1b318f40a6fcc0caeb9d0f92.png](http://c0848462.cdn.cloudfiles.rackspacecloud.com/8b7e0e7d1b318f40a6fcc0caeb9d0f92.png)

view in action here
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8DdPnOjOCgM#t=5m25

Comment: could you post an image on the view that you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[RadioGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html)

Comment: Takes up way too much space. Any 3rd party libraries that do the trick?